# jquery form submit can't handle success/error notifications

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to show a success notification if the submit was successful with [this](https://github.com/simple-notify/simple-notify) js notify library but it's doesn't works.

If I change the `new Notify({ ... })` function to a simple `alert("success");` then the alert is showing up...

But if I insert the same js code in the browser's Console then it's showing the notify ...

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title"><h6>Title</h6></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="content"><h6>Content</h6></label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="edit">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
 $("#edit").click(function() {

     var title = $("#title").val();
     var content = $("#content").val();
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "edit.php",
         data: {
            title: title,
            content: content
         },
         cache: false,
         success: function(data) {
            new Notify({
                status: 'success',
                title: 'Test',
                text: 'Success',
                effect: 'fade',
                speed: 300,
                customClass: null,
                customIcon: null,
                showIcon: true,
                showCloseButton: true,
                autoclose: false,
                autotimeout: 3000,
                gap: 20,
                distance: 20,
                type: 1,
                position: 'right top'
            })
         },
         error: function(xhr, status, error) {
             console.error(xhr);
         }
     });
      
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-notify@0.5.5/dist/simple-notify.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-notify@0.5.5/dist/simple-notify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery is included in my page, if I paste this example to my code then works well for me too...  but if I want to send the form's data then the page is just reloading immadiatelly because the method is post in the form so it's automatically reload the page, and the notify doesn't showing up. And no errors in the console.

Comment: I see the issue now - I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement in your comment under the question clarifies the issue:

> I want to send the form's data then the page is just reloading immadiatelly and the notify doesn't showing up

The issue is because you've not called `preventDefault()` on the event which is raised. Therefore the form is still submit through the standard manner and a page redirect occurs. As you're using AJAX you need to prevent this behaviour.

Also note that it's slightly more semantic to hook the event handler to the `submit` event of the `form` element instead of the `click` of the submit `button`. Try this:

```js
$("form").on('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop form submission

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "edit.php",
    data: {
      title: $("#title").val(),
      content: $("#content").val()
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      new Notify({
        status: 'success',
        title: 'Test',
        text: 'Success',
        effect: 'fade',
        speed: 300,
        customClass: null,
        customIcon: null,
        showIcon: true,
        showCloseButton: true,
        autoclose: false,
        autotimeout: 3000,
        gap: 20,
        distance: 20,
        type: 1,
        position: 'right top'
      })
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.error(xhr);
    }
  });
});
```